# Retrieving values from an Ajax post in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I submitting a form by using an ajax request which posts values to a php script which then stores those values in a database. This is my ajax post:

```
            $.ajax({

                type:"POST",
                url: "wp-content/plugins/super-plugin/process.php",
                'data': 'datastring',
                success: function() {

                    $('#formwrapper').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact form submitted!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>").hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                    });
                }
            });
```

And this is my PHP file:

```
    $full = explode("&", $_POST["data"]);
    $fname = explode(":", $full[0]);
    $name = $fname[1];
    $femail = explode(":", $full[1]);
    $email = $femail[1];
    $fphone = explode(":", $full[2]);
    $phone = $fphone[1];

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Andrew", "Change0", "plugindatadb");
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO data (Name, Email, Phone) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone')");
```

The data in datastring is formatted by "name:Bo&email:bob@mail&phone:0786754333". However for some reason I can't use those variables sent in my php script? For some reason the php script does not run as well.

Comment: All you're sending is the string `datastring`, what did you expect ?

Comment: Also, Wordpress has it's own way of setting up ajax, you should use it.

Comment: SQL Injection spotted, Undefined Index spotted, unhandled Exception spotted, bad practice spotted

Comment: Ah I see, the quotes around the data being sent meant I was sending the string instead of values contained in that string? Why would the php script  still not run though ?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you set formatted query params in variable datastring, then in that case, you should use that like shown below in ajax request (remove quotes for data and datastring).

```
$.ajax({

                type:"POST",
                url: "wp-content/plugins/super-plugin/process.php",
                data: datastring,
                success: function() {

                    $('#formwrapper').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact form submitted!</h2>")
                    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>").hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `''` from datastring ,

```
data: datastring
```

bt this is not proper way to pass data pass into json like data ,

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "wp-content/plugins/super-plugin/process.php",
    'data': {
              name:"Bo",email:"bob@mail",phone:"0786754333"
            },
    success: function() {

        $('#formwrapper').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact form submitted!</h2>")
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>").hide().fadeIn(1500, function() {
            $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
        });
    }
});
```

and into php page.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in:

```
'data': 'datastring',
```

If "datastring" is a variable, as indicated by your description of it's format, those values shouldn't be in quotes. So:

```
data: datastring,
```

Secondly, if your PHP script assumes that the data passed in can be split into various components and it accesses those array elements without first verifying that the data is in the required format (or at least that those array elements exist) then it will throw an exception if the data is invalid. This is currently happening because the data is 'datastring'. You should always validate input parameters as it saves time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `data` in **`ajax`** call as

```
data : { datastring : datastring },
```

In php access it like `$_POST['datastring']`.